# MySQL Regexp dot(any) doesn't match accentuated character

Tags: mysql, regex

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)  `.` should match any character, but it doesn't match accentuated characters.

```
mysql> select 'test' regexp 't.st';
+----------------------+
| 'test' regexp 't.st' |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'tést' regexp 't.st';
+-----------------------+
| 'tést' regexp 't.st'  |
+-----------------------+
|                     0 |
+-----------------------+
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there anyway to match any characters including special/accentuated characters?

My database collation is `utf8_general_ci` and I tried some different collations using the collate command on the test queries with no success.

Comment: UPDATE: This behavior is (mostly) fixed in MySQL 8.0.4 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html - handles as UTF-16 chunks. "Characters within the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane, which includes characters used by most modern languages" [are handled correctly].  LIMITATION: beyond 2-byte are multiple chunks, so may not match according to collation rules.

Answer (score 2):

Following MySQL documentation:

> Warning
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

So you shouldn't do it this way.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html